# Why doesn't the following jquery code work?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am trying to query the database to find if the username typed by the user is already in the database. If yes then it should display message "already exist!" but instead of displaying the message I get the following error in my browser :

[image: 500 internal server error]

I have stored the username "ahti" in my database.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validate/$',views.validateForm),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from librarysystem.models import Users
from django.http import JsonResponse

def validateForm(request):
   username = request.GET.get('username',None)
   data = {
      'is_taken' : Users.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
   }
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

**my jquery code :**

```js
function validateForm() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/librarysystem/validate/',
    data: {
      'username': username
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.is_taken) {
        alert("already taken!");
      }
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").keyup(validateForm);
});
```

Comment: The issue is url 'localhost:8000/librarysystem/validate/?username=a' you try to reach by jQuery return 500 code (that means server-side error). You should check logs of your django server.

Comment: why do i get alert message twice ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the browser tools, where your error shows, to see the traceback coming from the server. What that would have told you is that you can't pass a queryset directly to JsonResponse; you need to serialize it properly.

However that doesn't actually seem to be what you want to do. You don't care about the data, you just care about whether there is a match. So you should pass the result of `.exists()` on that queryset, which will give you a boolean:

```
data = {
  'is_taken' : Users.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists()
}
```